# Tooltip in Typescript. I am totally new to typescript, I wanted to implement mouse over in typescript for d3 stacked bar chart. Any help appreciated

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js

Please let me know how can I proceed? This is the following code I am using to see and facing some issues. I have been trying few changes many times but didn't get output. I am not understanding that how to call createtooltip, I am literally new to all this, can anyone guide what should be called?

The error I am getting is createtooltip is declared but never called.

```
 private initSvg() {
    this.createTooltip = d3.select('body').append("div")
    .classed('chart-tooltip', true)
    .style('display', 'none');
    let element = this.chartContainer.nativeElement;
    this.svg = d3.select(element)
    .append('svg')
    .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
    .attr('class', 'chart')
    .attr('width', this.w)
    .attr('height', this.h)
    .attr("viewBox", "0 0 800 600");
    this.chart = this.svg.append('g')
    .classed('chart-contents', true)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.margin.left + "," + this.margin.top + ")");
    this.layersBarArea = this.chart.append('g')
    .classed('layers', true);
}
 private drawAxis(){
    this.xAxis = this.chart.append('g')
    .classed('x axis', true)
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + this.height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(this.x).ticks(7))
    .selectAll("text")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("dx", "-.8em")
    .attr("dy", ".15em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)" );
    this.chart.append("text")
    .attr("y", this.height + 40)
    .attr("x", (this.width/2))
    .classed('axis-title', true)
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .style('stroke', 'none');
    this.yAxis = this.chart.append('g')
    .classed('y axis', true)
    .call(d3.axisLeft(this.y).ticks(7));
    this.chart.append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 0 - 60)
    .attr("x", 0 - (this.height / 2))
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .style('stroke', 'none')
    .classed('axis-title', true);
 }
 private updateChart(stackData:any){
    console.log("Update Chart");
    this.stackedSeries = this.stack(stackData);
    console.log("Look Here", this.stackedSeries);
    this.chart.selectAll(".layers").remove();
    var new_layer = this.chart.append('g')
    .classed('layers', true);
    this.x.domain(this.data.cpmans.map((d:any)=>{return d.label;}));
    this.y.domain([0, +d3.max(this.stackedSeries, function(d:any){return d3.max(d, (d:any)=>{return d[1];})})]);
    this.xAxis.transition().call(d3.axisBottom(this.x));
    this.yAxis.transition().call(d3.axisLeft(this.y));

    this.layersBar = new_layer.selectAll('.layer')
    .data(this.stackedSeries)
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .classed('layer', true)
    .style('fill', (d:any,i:any)=>{return this.colors[i];});
    this.x.domain(this.data.cpmans.map((d:any)=>{return d.label;}));
    this.y.domain([0, +d3.max(this.stackedSeries, function(d:any){return d3.max(d, (d:any)=>{return d[1];})})]);
    this.layersBar.selectAll('rect')
    .data((d:any)=>{return d;})
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('y', (d:any)=>{return this.y(d[1]);})
    .attr('x', (d:any, i:any)=>{return this.x(d.data.label);})
    .attr('width', this.x.bandwidth()/2)
    .attr('height', (d:any, i:any)=>{ return this.y(d[0]) - this.y(d[1]);})
    .on("mouseover", function() { this.tooltip.style("display", null); })
    .on("mouseout", function() { this.tooltip.style("display", "none"); })
    .on("mousemove", function(d) {
    var xPosition = d3.mouse(this)[0] - 15;
    var yPosition = d3.mouse(this)[1] - 25;
    this.tooltip.attr("transform", "translate(" + xPosition + "," + yPosition + ")");
    this.tooltip.select("text").text(d.y);
        });

 }
 private createTooltip(){
     this.tooltip = this.svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("display", "none");
    this.tooltip.append("rect")
    .attr("width", 30)
    .attr("height", 20)
    .attr("fill", "white")
    .style("opacity", 0.5);
     this.tooltip.append("text")
    .attr("x", 15)
    .attr("dy", "1.2em")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("font-size", "12px")
    .attr("font-weight", "bold");
 }
```

Comment: Refer [this](https://github.com/monkeyscript/monkey-charts/blob/master/projects/monkey-charts/src/lib/components/vertical-bar/vertical-bar.component.ts). It's simple implementation of bar chart in Angular using D3.

Answer (score 0):

`this.createTooltip` is a member function of your class, but in `initSvg()` you overwrite it with a d3 selection. Therefore you cannot call the function anymore and your editor shows you this 'error'. I think a lot of people are very willing to help you, but you need to try and keep your question small. For a general example on bar charts with D3, the comment of @Arcteezy seems like a good starting point.